# No data showing up in Time Series chart for Cloud MySQL DATETIME column

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to put together a Data Studio dashboard for a client, and am having trouble getting a Time Series chart to show data. The data is coming from a DATETIME column in a Cloud MySQL database table.

I've verified that the data is in the table, and when I try to show the data in a different format (bar chart, pie graph, etc.) it shows up fine. I've also tried using different metrics. I'm fairly new to Data Studio, so possible it's something simple I'm missing, but am sufficiently stumped that I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: be more specific, show your code, what you tried, errors etc. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with converting DATE objects in MySQL to Google Data Studio. I had to create a new field in Data Studio using the format:

```
TODATE([date_field_name], 'DEFAULT_DASH', '%Y%m%d')
```

I then used that as the dimension and the chart showed up fine.